# how do I edit joomla htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

my joomla site has a default htaccess file   but it does not contain a section to deny from  ipaddresses

There is alot of content in the default htaccess file.

Where can I put my Deny from  ipaddresses   in this file?

the top of the file has
rewriteengine on
rewritecond    a couple of times

then there is a large section of differing options which appear to be commented out

followed by some more rewritecond lines at the bottom.

Comment: You might get even more helpful answers if you put as much effoxrt into your questions as you want others to put into your answers. 1. Show us your `.htaccess `file. 2. Make an effort to answer your own question, read the comments in the `.htaccess` file, read the docs on the Joomla project site. 3. Tell us what you've tried already. Etc.

Comment: Hi Jim  I was not sure how priviate my .htaccess file was so I did not know what of I could post.  I am glad you took the time to consider that before you replied.  I noticed my .htaccess file had information in it about my site so I did not post it.   I have read the .htaccess file on my Joomla site, and did not see any comments about where I would put any deny info.... so I searched this site, did not notice anyone posting a similar question, so I wanted to make sure I did not wreck my htaccess file on my site.  I also googled for examples and found none.

Comment: The default htaccess.txt file distributed with Joomla is public information. If you haven't edited it, then it contains nothing confidential. I still think you will get better answers by posting your `.htaccess` file. Also, you should read the _Joomla_ docs at http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist , and learn about Apache's .htaccess mechanism at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: This is the top of the file
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTPS} off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
rewriterule ^$ "https\:\/\/mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L] #4ec9420f6ec54

Do I put the Deny from lines above that?

Comment: Editing your question, to improve it, is better than posting comments. There is a limit to how many comments StackOverflow accepts. You can edit your question many times.

Comment: Did you try putting the `Deny from` lines above the `rewriteengine on` line?  What happened when you tried it? See my answer below. "You will have to learn how your web server and Joomla installation work, and do some experiments."

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess mechanism is complicated, and very site-specific. You aren't likely to get an answer that is both simple and reliable. You will have to do learn how your web server and Joomla installation work, and do some experiments.

Articulate clearly what you are trying to accomplish, and why.  Is this part of a security plan for your site?  Are you trying to block attackers, or block access to everyone except known safe IP addresses? Which IP addresses are you trying to block? Have you thought about what happens if attackers move to a different IP address, not on your block list?

Read the [**Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html). I've linked to the version for Apache 2.4, but you should read the documentation for the version of Apache you use.

Read the [Joomla! **Security Checklist** documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist). There is an [*htaccess examples (security)* article](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29). It includes a use of `deny from`, though probably not the usage you had in mind. You should also take a look through the [index of the **Security category** of the documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aSecurity).

You will need to do experiments, so be sure you have a way of trying a change to the `.htaccess` file, and reverting to a previous version of the file if the change behaves badly. You could, for example, keep of copy of the original file, and when a change causes problems, upload the original file to the site, overwriting the problematic file.

You will need to decide which changes to make by knowing what web server and what version you are using, and what version of Joomla! you are using.

All that said, I agree with Jon Lin. If you are seeking to deny access from specific IP addresses, add such lines to the top of the .htaccess file, after the comments but before the lines:

```
########## Begin - RewriteEngine enabled
RewriteEngine On
########## End - RewriteEngine enabled
```

But be prepared for this to not work the first time, due to the specific details about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you add the `Deny From 1.2.3.4` stuff, but if would probably be more efficient to add them above any mod_rewrite directives, so that those IP addresses would get passed through for a 403 response right away without having the request URI pass through the rewrite engine.

Comment: so I could put it as the first line in the file? ahead of the rewriteengine on   line?